# scraping reviews from a data tab with python

Tags: python, tabs, screen-scraping

I'm having trouble scraping multiple pages. I think my error is somewhere in baseurl+str, but am not sure how to move forward. I appreciate any thoughts and suggestions.

base page-- https://www.premier1supplies.com/p/prima-heat-lamp

```
import requests  
from lxml import html      
import pandas as pd
import time 
from IPython.display import display, clear_output 

baseURL = "https://www.premier1supplies.com/p/prima-heat-lamp"

mypath = '//*[@id="product-information-tab-pane-reviews"]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/p[2]'

reviews_all =[]

for i in range (5):
    URL=baseURL+str(i+1)
    page = requests.get(URL) 
    root = html.fromstring(page.content)
    reviews = [s.text for s in root.xpath(mypath)]
    reviews_all.extend(reviews)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    clear_output()
    print(URL)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Review': reviews_all})
```

I can pull from the first page fine with the following code, but pulling out multiple pages is where I'm running into issues.
Page 2 of the review tab—
https://www.premier1supplies.com/p/prima-heat-lamp?slug=prima-heat-lamp&offset=5&limit=5#product-information-reviews

```
from lxml import html      
import pandas as pd
import time 
from IPython.display import display, clear_output 

mypath = '//*[@id="product-information-tab-pane-reviews"]/div/div[4]/div/div/div[2]/p[2]'
URL = "https://www.premier1supplies.com/p/prima-heat-lamp?slug=prima-heat-lamp&offset=0&limit=5#product-information-reviews"
page = requests.get(URL)
root = html.fromstring(page.content)
reviews = [s.text_content() for s in root.xpath(mypath)]
```

Comment: What exactly is the error your getting?

Comment: Also does the website not have a public api that would be better accessing if not have youu considered beutiful soup for the parsing?

Comment: It's that when I create the data frame, it's blank. I'm not reading getting info into it.

Comment: Not sure about the public API

Comment: And have not yet considered beautiful soup for parsing, still fledgling in my background knowledge.

Comment: I can't see that you've used pandas to make a dataframe at any point?

Comment: Also please provide a minimal reporducable example see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Also looking at the URL you use there's a limit option on it. IF you set that to the number of reviews on the page it will display them all at once. You could try to get the number of reviews from the page using Xpaths and then call the original URL with that number as the limit argument. This will be more general as it will work no matter how many reviews there are.

Comment: Tasty213, that was most helpful! Thank you. I changed the limit and that allowed me to pull all reviews. So, that gets me the content I need.      Still curious if I can parse multiple pages.

Answer (score 0):

A key thing to understand when writing a custom API is to understand what each part of the URL you're interacting with means. This is so you can understand how to modify it to get what you want. So in order to understand the URL i would suggest the following steps:

for this URL: https://www.premier1supplies.com/p/prima-heat-lamp?slug=prima-heat-lamp&offset=0&limit=5#product-information-reviews
with the following reviews`[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

1. Get the base URL, this is the simplest for that the URL can be while still pointing to the root page. In general, this means removing any unnecessary GET tags so: https://www.premier1supplies.com/p/prima-heat-lamp#product-information-reviews
2. Add each tag sequentially to understand what each one does. In this case, the slug variable is just another pointer to the right article and can be left out
3. Offset is how many far along the list of reviews should be displayed. for instance offset = 0 would display all the reviews, offset = 5 would display the reviews from 5 onwards.
4. Limit is the total number of reviews to display. A limit of 5 displays five reviews from offset onwards whereas a limit of 10 displays 10 reviews from offset onwards

Knowing how the URL is constructed we can now programmatically assemble our requests as such:

```
base = 'https://www.premier1supplies.com/p/prima-heat-lamp'
tag = '#product-information-reviews'
offset = 0
limit = 5
URL = base + '?offset=' + str(offset) + '&limit=' + str(limit) + tag
```

This will create a URL with the specified GET parameters. You then simply have to keep requesting pages incrementing the offset parameter (by the limit otherwise you will either miss some reviews or get duplicate reviews) each time until you detect there are no more reviews and the only entry is the write a review option as seen here: https://www.premier1supplies.com/p/prima-heat-lamp?offset=15000&limit=5#product-information-reviews

Alternatively, you could increase the limit to get all reviews in one request. However, this has the problem that you might pull too many reviews all at once and the request becomes to large to handle.